# why have double extention after being caught in ransomware

Tags: virus

I think usually when you get ransomware, you add one ransomware extension to one file But in some cases, there are two ransomware extensions added to one file, and what is this

ex) 1.txt.readme199909.exe.readme201011.bat

why have two extention?

two ransomeware attack one pc together?

Comment: What is a "ransomware extension"?